# List to BiMap in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, guava, collectors

I have a input which is of type: `List<List<String>>`.

An example input:

```
[A, A1Name]
[B, B1Name]
```

I want to convert it to BiMap

```
A -> A1Name
B -> B1Name
```

What is the best way to achieve this:

Currently I am doing:

```
final BiMap<String, String> myMap = HashBiMap.create();
lines.forEach(
    (tokens) -> {
        myMap.put(tokens.get(0), tokens.get(1));
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with what you have.

Comment: I was thinking, if any way to utilize stream.map() or stream.collect()

Comment: There is no standard collector for BiMap, since it's not a standard Java class, and Guava doesn't target Java 8 yet. You could write your own collector, but why bother when those 3 lines of code do the job just fine?

Comment: There are many [ad hoc libraries](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=guava+java+8) providing Java 8 collectors for Guava as a bridge until officially supported.

Answer (score 9):

Since `BiMap` implements `Map`, you can use the `toMap` collector.  To replicate the behavior of your loop (duplicate keys silently override values, duplicate values throw exception), you can do the following:

```
BiMap<String,String> m = lines.stream().collect(toMap(
    x->x.get(0), x->x.get(1), (a,b)->b, HashBiMap::create
));
```

As an aside, when you are not sure how to convert your code to streams, 3-argument `collect` provides a way to convert the iterative code almost verbatim:

```
BiMap<String,String> m = lines.stream().collect(
        HashBiMap::create,
        (bm,t) -> bm.put(t.get(0), t.get(1)),
        BiMap::putAll
);
```